# NullPointer err when trying to create a Service class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So I had no problems with my app until I decided that it's better to have a Service class to do all the logic stuff. And when i copy the exact same code that i initially had, i get NullPointer error.

This is what i had and it worked all well:

```
User user = userRepository.findById(id).get();
```

This is what i have in Service class:

```
public User findUserById(Integer id)
    {
        User user = userRepository.findById(id).get();
        return user;
    }
```

And this is what i call:

```
private UserService userService = new UserService();
User user = userService.findUserById(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling `new UserService()` it's not a Spring bean and won't get autowired.

There are multiple ways to [create a Spring bean](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_beans_and_dependency_injection):

1. Annotate your class with `@Service` and making sure it's part of the component scan for your app. Also make sure the repository field is annotated with `@Autowired` or that your service class has a constructor that accepts the repository as an argument.

```java
    @Service
    public class UserService {

        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;
    }
```

2. Create a class annotated with `@Configuration` and then add a `@Bean` method that returns a new instance of your service:

```java
    @Configuration
    public class UserServiceConfig {

        @Bean
        public UserService userService(UserRepository userRepository) {
            return new UserService(userRepository); // could also use a setter instead
        }
    }
```